# How can I create a range display from a list of non consecutive numbers?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I made a bash script to display numbers in range and I wonder if it's possible to do the same in Sheets without scripting.

I got in a column (let's say A) a list of numbers, for example :

```
001
002
004
012
013
014
...
```

and I have a variable prefix in a cell (let's say B1="PREFIX")

Is there a way to display the result as below :

```
PREFIX001-PREFIX002
PREFIX004
PREFIX012-PREFIX014
...
```

Thank you by advance for your help !

Comment: What is the pattern that generates the result? What happens after 014?

Comment: It's for server name reservation so I list existing servers and the result is the listing of all non already used names in the 001-999 range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be done. For example `A3:A` range has the numbers, `B1` will be the prefix and `B3:B` will have the resulting rows.

[image]

The formula is only (as it is an array formula) in `B3`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
    REGEXREPLACE(
      REGEXREPLACE(
        TEXTJOIN(
          ",",
          True, 
            IF(
              NOT(ISNUMBER(A3:A)),
                "",
                IF(
                    NOT(ISNUMBER({""; OFFSET(A3:A, 0, 0, ROWS(A3:A) - 1)}))
                  + NOT(ISNUMBER({A4:A; ""}))
                  + (  ISNUMBER({""; OFFSET(A3:A, 0, 0, ROWS(A3:A) - 1)})
                     * (A3:A <> {""; OFFSET(A3:A, 0, 0, ROWS(A3:A) - 1)} + 1))
                  + (  ISNUMBER({A4:A; ""})
                       * (A3:A <> {A4:A; ""} - 1)),
                    TEXT(A3:A, "00#"),
                    ""
                  )
            )
          & IF(
              ISNUMBER({A4:A; ""})
            * (A3:A = {A4:A; ""} - 1),
              "-",
              ""
          )
        ),
        "(?:-,)+",
        "-"
      ),
      "\d+",
      B1 & "$0"
    ),
    ","
  ))
)
```

Here is a sample sheet with step by step description of the solution: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mJJZov8BJ14RufBSY4jTTfMN5qUpoNzDWbXB9qiuYkQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Awesome it works perfectly, thank you very much !
In the meantime I found a solution with multiple columns and formulas but it's far less elegant than yours so I'll dig it to understand the way it works.

Comment: @ToPiquette I did it in multiple columns first (easier to tune), step by step, then combined it. That's because people usually need as few columns as possible. This  solution could be easily taken apart function by function from the inside out. Nice question btw, thnaks for that!

Comment: @ToPiquette added a sample sheet with detailed description of the steps for you.

Answer (score 0):

@kishkin

Thank you so much for taking the time to do that ! I made a copy to check it, that's very kind of you !
I made mine with multiple columns but in the nasty way (I'm quite new with Sheets but I love it so far) :

[image]

to group consecutive numbers :

```
=IF(CNUM(V2)=CNUM(V1)+1,IF(REGEXMATCH(W1,"-"),LEFT(W1,CHERCHE("-",W1)-1)&"-"&V2,V1&"-"&V2),V2)
```

to replace lonelies that are part of a range :

```
=IF(LEFT(W3,2)=LEFT(W2,2),0,W2)
```

Split the range to calculate range value later :

```
=SPLIT(X2,"-")
```

To calculate the range except for 0 values :

```
=IF(Z2-Y2+1<0,1,Z2-Y2+1)
```

To remove all the 0 so only the ranges remain :

```
=filter(X2:X,X2:X>0)
```

To align the totals with the ranges (useful for group reservations for a project)

```
=filter(AA2:AA,X2:X>0)
```

After that, it's just adding the prefix and add some text (sorry for the french).
As I told you it's not as sexy as your solution ^^